# Redis reddison client slow put

Tags: redis, redisson

Redisson client when doing a put or set operation always gets a connection first. Is there a way to reuse the same connection and reduce the cost of operations

Answer (score 0):

> Redisson client when doing a put or set operation always gets a connection first

It uses pooled connections. Never creates it each time. During first operation codec may require warmup. You can try to use simple StringCodec.

Answer (score -1):

I experimented with jedis client that reuses the same connection. I am using that for now.